# AWS-Connection Issue between Web server and database server in the same region

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5, aws-directory-service

I have set up a web server and database server in AWS as shown the diagram below

[aws diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gRq8.jpg)
**Web Server:**

1. OS: Windows Server 2012 R2
2. Application hosted: VB.NET application in .NET 3.5 framework
3. Web Server :MS  IIS  8.5

**Database Server:**

1. OS: Oracle Linux 7.4
2. Database : Oracle 12c Release 1

**AWS related Specification:**

1. Web Server and Database Server are located in different VPC but  hosted in  same root account
2. Database Server is associated with an elastic ip ; because of this elastic ip , database is accessible from public network
3. in the database server, TCP port 1521 is opened and accessible via telnet from public network
4. From web server we can access the database server via sqlplus or oracle sql developer
5. *I have configured IIS to run with a local web server account*

**Issue:**

1. When I run the application from IIS server, it says that it cannot access the database

**Questions:**
I have googled about this issue and I presume that there is major factors which is causing the problem

1. Since IIS is configured with local account , it may not have access to reach the database account

help me to get out of this please, I know the application architecture is too bad, it is my development environment and i am new to this AWS .

thanks for your time

Comment: Why (according to the diagram) is your database in a public subnet? External access can be useful, but unless restricted by security groups or similar it can be a security risk. If you can access the database from your web server using any tool but not using IIS it's a configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your Database should not be on a public subnet. If they need to be in a different VPC for any reason, you should peer those VPC's and move the database to a private subnet. You are subject to latency over the public internet with your database connectivity the way it is currently setup. If you want better network performance I would move the database to one of the two setups and retest, peered VPC or same vpc.

[VPC Peering Setup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/PeeringGuide/Welcome.html)

[AWS white paper on Running Oracle in the cloud](https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/strategies-for-migrating-oracle-database-to-aws.pdf)